# SQl Azure Database size increase

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We recently upgrade our SQL Azure database from Business Edition to S1 performance level. Though Microsoft suggest us S0 Level, but we never get the performance we needed (or were getting in business edition).

However my question is that after 4 days of operation, we notice a increase in database size from 970MB to 1.5 GB. Though we never add much data, we hardly reach even 1GB of Data size in our 3 months of operation (from 970 mb).

We try to rebuild index that reduce the size  about 300 MB, but again it gain it's size in couple of days.

we didn't find any thing in Azure documentation that related to it. so if anyone has any experience or knowledge please share with us. Thanks.

EDIT:

As I was expecting it seems log size issue, as I try to rebuild indexes again, and after 1 hr the size automatically reduce to 1.3 GB which seems legitimate considering that we add some more data to database and were unable to delete some data (as Database is timing out another issue. ).

Comment: This increase in database size is not because of increase in Transaction log file size is it? how are you checking your database size ?

Comment: @M.Ali I am checking size in azure portal, and I don't know where i can check Transaction log size in Azure SQL. and no it is not the log size as in our regular working we never have that much of data transfer that it create 300 mb of log in just one or two days.

Comment: This shouldn't be log size issue. Are you on SQLDB V12 or V11? If in V12 you can log file size by sys.database_files. Can you run the below query to see what each table / index taking: SELECT SUM(used_page_count) AS total_number_of_used_pages, 
    SUM (row_count) AS total_number_of_rows 
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('HumanResources.Employee')